# Avoid duplicate images in Prestashop 1.6 when import CSV

Tags: combinations, prestashop-1.6, cvsimport

I am having issues with Prestashop 1.6 and I hope I could find some help in here.

Basically, I uploaded a csv with all the products and everything worked fine. After that I also uploaded another csv with the combinations that include the images related to the product colors and, again, no problems, it simply adds these images to the previously uploaded with the products.

The issue occurs when I update the combinations csv. It seems it duplicates the images from the previous csv. I tried to add a column "delete existing images" set to 1 (=yes) but the problem is that it also removes the product images!

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance,

Pat

Answer (score 0):

PrestaShop fits the image of the first csv as an image product.
Even if you set to 1 "delete existing images", PrestaShop does not find images because that function deletes the entity attribute and not the product.

My advice is do not upload images of products with attributes in the first csv. General product will look like the image pricipale Default Product.